# Can we stream an array of files to WCF service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I want to stream multiple files to WCF but WCF not allowing me.
Now I want to send an array of files, Can we stream an array of files to WCF service?
Will these files be serialized in one stream?

Answer (score 0):

you need to work in stream mode, have you tried to work with message contract?

```
[MessageContract]
public class UploadFileRequest
{
        [MessageHeader]
        public string filePath;
        [MessageBodyMember]
        public Stream bytes;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IStreamTest
{
      [OperationContract]
      Stream GetStream(string filePath);

      [OperationContract]
       void PutStream(UploadFileRequest request);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am already working with message contract.